# how to generate auto data in sequence even when after re run the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, auto-generate

i am doing a project on C# in window form

i currently trying to do a button which can randomly create student but , those student should tag with a student id which should be auto generate..but i not sure how should i do the auto generate...i did something in the below code, but found that the student id is not in sequence...i need it to be in sequence is there a way to create a auto generate student id in sequence and tag with the random student data??
**is student that is random and student id is sequence...the sequence i mean is it 1, 2,3....and i already have a primary key**

thanks in advance

i create a class for the random data

```
public static class StudentRegister
  {
    private static Random s = new Random();
    static string[] student = new string[] { "wei ting", "jin ling", "wei wei", "shi ya", "yi ting", "an qin", "lian en"};
    public static string GetStudent()
    {
      return student[s.Next(0, student.Count())];
    }

    static string[] studentID = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"" };
    public static string GetStudentID()
    {
      return studentID[s.Next(0, studentID.Count())];
    }


  }
```

**i try something like this: edited:** but got a problem after i stop it will and re-run my form again, it call back 1 again, how am i going to  change the code? can tell me...i  want to it to continue like example previous i have already  insert, 3 random name so the student id should 1,2,3 right, then i close this form and re-run  again the form, and insert another 3 random name it start from 1 again not 4

```
public static class StudentRegister
 {
  static int NextID = 0;
  private static Random s = new Random();
  static string[] student = new string[] { "wei ting", "jin ling", "wei wei", "shi ya",
    "yi ting", "an qin", "lian en" };
  public static string GetStudent()
  {
   return student[s.Next(0, student.Count())];
  }

  public static string GetStudentID()
  {
   ++NextID;
   return NextID.ToString();
  }
 }
```

Comment: You need to specify what kind of sequence you are looking for, because sequence and random are somewhat opposites.  For example, do you mean you need each ID to be random, but each ID larger than the last?

Comment: @aresAvatar did you get what i mean??

Comment: If you want the sequence to be incremented, bemused's answer should work for you.

Comment: @AresAvatar i don't understand the link @bemused give...if can it will be nice if you can show me how it work out

Comment: bemused showed you how to set up your database so that you do not need to insert the ID -- the database will generate it for you, as long as you set up the ID column correctly.  Mark the schema the way it's shown in the links, and then your insert will cause the ID field to automatically increment in the database.

Comment: @AresAvatar, but where should i change, i dont even know where should i start changing it at?, so  that why i was hoping to ask you use my code show me where should i make the changes...

Answer (score 1):

I would not handle auto-incrementing a unique id in your c# code. Let MSSQL do the work. Then you can insert new records (containing StudentName and whatever else you want) and the ID will be generated for you:

http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Edit:

Okay, this is untested but something like this... I'd change the C# code:

```
public static class StudentRegister
{
    private static Random s = new Random();
    static string[] student = new string[] { "wei ting", "jin ling", "wei wei", "shi ya", "yi ting", "an qin", "lian en" };
    public static string GetStudent()
    {
        return student[s.Next(0, student.Count())];
    }
}


private void btnStudentAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=student;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StudentList (StudentName) VALUES (@Name)", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = StudentRegister.GetStudent();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    GridviewBind();  //bind the create data back to datagridview
}
```

You'll need to add the identity column to your table. I'm assuming there's no data in the table you need to keep, so just drop and recreate the table.

```
DROP TABLE StudentList;

CREATE TABLE StudentList
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentName varchar (15),
    StudentId int IDENTITY(1,1)
);
```

Comment: i have a primary key already, i need a auto generate student id to tag with the random data of student name

Comment: can you use my code and do out something what you say, cause i don't get what you mean, i have not try before , so it will be nice of you to show me...thanks

Comment: i use the database in the visual studio,  i create table ,the code you give for the table, how should i suppose to change?cause i never use the code before...(the part on drop table.....)